# LINQ: IAsyncGrouping and IGrouping conflict

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
var result = await _issueRepository
                      .List(l => true)
                      .Include(l => l.Issue)
                      .Where(l => l.Issue.Deleted == false 
                          && linkedIncidentsTotal
                             .Any(x => x.Contains(l.Lable.LabelTitle)))
                      .GroupBy(l => l.Lable)
                      .ToListAsync();
```

And when it executes, i am getting error:

> Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IAsyncGrouping`2[mobo.Models.Lables,mobo.Models.LableIssues]]'
>   cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[mb.Models.Lables,mb.Models.LableIssues]]'

Comment: @CodeCaster this is not a duplicate, this issue is not related at all. Unmark this as duplicate.

Comment: What is `linkedIncidentsTotal` and where does it come from?

Comment: What version of .net are you using