# LINQ: IAsyncGrouping and IGrouping conflict (2)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

THIS ISSUE IS A DUPLICATE OF 
[LINQ: IAsyncGrouping and IGrouping conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073952/linq-iasyncgrouping-and-igrouping-conflict?noredirect=1&lq=1)
... which has been marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question.

I have this code:

```
var result = await _issueRepository.List(l => true)
                       .Include(l => l.Issue)
                       .Where(l => l.Issue.Deleted == false 
                           && linkedIncidentsTotal.Any(x => x.Contains(l.Lable.LabelTitle)))
                       .GroupBy(l => l.Lable)
                       .ToListAsync();
```

And when it executes, i am getting error:

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable1[System.Linq.IAsyncGrouping2[mobo.Models.Lables,mobo.Models.LableIssues]]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable1[System.Linq.IGrouping2[mb.Models.Lables,mb.Models.LableIssues]]'

Comment: So why are you, a different OP, posting a duplicate of another question?  The ability to reopen a question already exists

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its just spamming an already existing question

Comment: @maccettura There is no ability to reopen the question as I am not the OP. The problem here is the person that incorrectly marked the question as duplicate, not me. How is this off-topic? Nobody answered the question because of that person's mistake.

Comment: Users with the appropriate level of reputation can _vote_ to re-open the question.   If you don't have the requisite reputation level to vote to re-open then do not take it upon yourself to just ask the same exact question again.  If the original question was closed in error it will be re-opened, or eventually deleted and the OP can ask their question again.

Comment: It was closed 8 months ago and nobody has done nothing. So you are suggesting to let the fate of my question's answer be in the hands of the OP and on community members who do not care about that incorrectly closed question. I need it answered now, not in 6 months...

Comment: Maybe the OP has solved its problem, but I have not

Comment: Well I would suggest not asking a word for word duplicate of the question.  The first question was clearly worded in a way that lead to a high reputation member to mark it as a duplicate.  Ask a _better_ question so you get a _better_ response.

Comment: I reopened the original question because the alleged duplicate actually didn't match. This question should be closed as duplicate of the original question as soon as the latter receives answers. @sixtstorm1 Please next time vote to reopen a question indicating the reason why and maybe trying to improve it.

Comment: @maccettura you have a point on that, question could be more clear.

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen with the latest EF Core 2.1, what version are you on? Might be a bug which has already been fixed.

Comment: Indeed, after some more reasearch this is a bug in EF Core, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10716 which is fixed in 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in EF Core https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10716 which is fixed in 2.1.